# Rails - expecting <"categories/index"> but rendering with <[]>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, minitest

I am trying to run a test but see the below error

> "CreateCategoriesTest#test_get_new_category_form_and_create_category [/Users/imcglobal/Desktop/RailsDevelopement/blog/test/integration/create_categories_test.rb:10]:
>   expecting <"categories/index"> but rendering with <[]>"

below are the test details

```
test "get new category form and create category" do
    get new_category_path
    assert_template 'categories/new'
    assert_difference 'Category.count', 1 do
        post categories_path, category: {name: "sports"}
    end
    assert_template 'categories/index' **#line 10**
    assert_match "sports", response.body
end


#categories controller
def index
    @categories = Category.all
end
```

My index file loops through categories object. Can anyone please let me know what i am missing. Thanks.

Comment: How does your controller look like? Which line is line 10 of your `create_categories_test.rb` in your example?

Comment: what does your CategoriesController#create action look like?

Comment: try to replace L#10 with `response.should redirect_to '/categories'`

Answer (score 1):

Just add `follow_redirect!` after the `post categories_path, category: {name: "sports"}`

```
post categories_path, category: {name: "sports"}
follow_redirect!
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post will help someone in the future.

you need to change

```
post categories_path, category: {name: "sports"}
```

to

```
post_via_redirect categories_path, category: {name: "sports"}
```